# Error in rasterizing shapefile by using pygeoprocessing

Tags: pygeoprocessing

While using pygeoprocessing rasterize() function to convert the shapefile into raster format I got the following error:

`0warning 1: failed to find field wt on layer pointshp, skipping.`

My script is as follows:

```
def vec2rast():

    source = ogr.Open("G:\Data\shashankdata\pointshp\pointshp.shp")
    layer = source.GetLayer()
    schema = {}
    ldefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
    for n in range(ldefn.GetFieldCount()):
        fdefn = ldefn.GetFieldDefn(n)
        schema[n] = fdefn.name
    print schema
    index = int(input("Enter index number corresponding to field"))
    pg.geoprocessing.rasterize("G:\Data\shashankdata\pointshp\pointshp.shp",
                               "G:\Data\shashankdata\LSMDATASET\MOSIAC\MOSIAC.tif", burn_values=[255],
                               option_list=["ATTRIBUTE= %s" % schema[index]], layer_index=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

this looks like it might be a GDAL related error. Specifically that it can't find the field `wt` in `pointshp.shp`. Is it possible that you're passing `wt` on the `["ATTRIBUTE= %s" % schema[index]` line but that there's no such field in `pointshp.shp`?